# Convert Dictionary in List of of strings in C#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, linq-to-objects

I have this code:

```
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
parameters.Add("param1", 100);
parameters.Add("param2", "ABC");
parameters.Add("param3", 1.2);
```

I need to generate the code below with the maximum performance possible, can use Linq, Lambda, etc..!?

```
var tableName = "table1"
var fields = "param1, param2, param3";
var values = "@param1, @param2, @param3"

var result = String.Format("INSERT INTO {0} ({1}) VALUES ({2})", tableName, fields, values);
```

> ... Execute Sql AddParamWithValue....(this is okay I can do it...)

Comment: Why are you concerned with performance of the code?  The database execution will take the lion's share of the total time.

Comment: Generally a good old fashioned for or foreach loop is performant enough

Comment: Yeah I know, but this code will run 1 million times... I ran my replication tool last night, It took 2.5 hours to sincronize all... but As I generated all the SQL's "insert into...." previously and put 1 million times in memory" my memory went up to 5 GB" in this way doing it just before running the Sql, and instead of saving the whole sql in memory, putting only a property point if the sql is "Insert, Update, Delete" my save a few GBs of memory...

Comment: Ah, I see, so that would be different. Interesting... For the fields, it is easy enough to do string.Join(",",parameters.Keys).  But I'm not sure about the values...

Comment: If you have to run it 1 million times you should be using Bulk inserts, you are going to tie up a lot of server resources trying to insert a million records 1 row at a time. BTW, I bulk inserted 86 million records in 20 minutes on a Raspberry Pi 2, 1 million shouldn't take 2.5 hours on SQL Server.

Comment: so is the issue speed performance or memory consumption, or both. The way I would convert my dictionary to keys or values, I use Dictionary.Keys and Dictionary.Values

Comment: When looking at performance, the first step should always be profiling. We can only guess where the bottlenecks are/memory is being consumed, especially without seeing all of your code.  A profiler will tell you what is going on, and which areas of code need attention.

Comment: Yes I tried the Bulk Insert, however this works for Inserts, what about my Updates or deletes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so, I did a little test and string.join works really well:

```
param = string.Join(",", parameters.Keys);
value = string.Join(",", parameters.Values);
```

Here is my test function:

```
private static void RunLoopTester()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Building dictionary...");
            var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            for(var i = 0;i< 10000;i++)
            {
                parameters.Add(string.Format("param{0}",i),string.Format("value{0}", i));
            }
            var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
            Console.WriteLine("Using foreach statement...");
            stopWatch.Start();
            var param = string.Empty;
            var value = string.Empty;
            foreach(var k in parameters.Keys)
            {
                param += string.Format("{0}{1}", string.IsNullOrEmpty(param) ? string.Empty : ",", k);
                value += string.Format("{0}{1}", string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? string.Empty : ",", parameters[k]);

            }
            stopWatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Elapsed Time: {0}", stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            Console.WriteLine("Using simple syntax...");
            param = string.Empty;
            value = string.Empty;
            stopWatch.Reset();
            stopWatch.Start();
            param = string.Join(",", parameters.Keys);
            value = string.Join(",", parameters.Values);
            stopWatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Elapsed Time: {0}", stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

And the results:

```
Pick your tester:
1: Timer Test
2: Loop Tester
2
Building dictionary...
Using foreach statement...
Elapsed Time: 1249
Using simple syntax...
Elapsed Time: 1
```

Edit: Post Accepted.  OP mentioned that @param was needed for the proc parameters.  This can be done by either put it in the key of the dictionary (much better) or, if you can't, then you can replace:

```
param = string.Join(",", parameters.Keys);
```

With:

```
param = string.Join(",", parameters.Keys).Replace("param","@param");
```

This increases the time to 2 milliseconds.  I tried using a linq select on the keys enumerable, but that increased the time to 4 milliseconds.  So the replace is more performant.